# Batch script to delete files older than 20 minutes

Tags: batch-file

Hi Iam new to batch scripting I want to create batch script which deletes the files older than 20 minutes.

I have searched the internet and found one batch script:

```bat
@echo off
:: Wmic removes regional differences - it has problems with commas in filenames.
setlocal

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "stamp=%YYYY% %MM% %DD% %HH% %Min%"

call :DateToMinutes %stamp% NowMins

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir * /a-d /b') do call :CheckMins "%%~fa"
pause
goto :EOF

:CheckMins
set "filestamp="
set "filemins="
set "MinsOld="
set "YY=" & set "YYYY=" & set "MM=" & set "DD="
set "HH=" & set "Min=" & set "Sec=" & set "dt="
set "file=%~1"
set "filea=%file:\=\\%"
WMIC DATAFILE WHERE name="%filea%" get lastmodified | find "." >file.tmp
for /f %%a in (file.tmp) do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "filestamp=%YYYY% %MM% %DD% %HH% %Min%"
del file.tmp 2>nul

if not defined yyyy goto :EOF

call :DateToMinutes %filestamp% FileMins

set /a MinsOld=%NowMins%-%FileMins%
:: echo Now:%NowMins% File:%FileMins% Fileage:%minsold% "%~1"
if %MinsOld% gtr 20 del "%file%"
goto :EOF

:DateToMinutes
setlocal
set yy=%1&set mm=%2&set dd=%3&set hh=%4&set nn=%5
if 1%yy% LSS 200 if 1%yy% LSS 170 (set yy=20%yy%) else (set yy=19%yy%)
set /a dd=100%dd%%%100,mm=100%mm%%%100
set /a z=14-mm,z/=12,y=yy+4800-z,m=mm+12*z-3,j=153*m+2
set /a j=j/5+dd+y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400-2472633
if 1%hh% LSS 20 set hh=0%hh%
if /i {%nn:~2,1%} EQU {p} if "%hh%" NEQ "12" set hh=1%hh%&set/a hh-=88
if /i {%nn:~2,1%} EQU {a} if "%hh%" EQU "12" set hh=00
if /i {%nn:~2,1%} GEQ {a} set nn=%nn:~0,2%
set /a hh=100%hh%%%100,nn=100%nn%%%100,j=j*1440+hh*60+nn
endlocal&set %6=%j%&goto :EOF
```

But it deletes the files from current directory. But my scenario is to delete the files from specific location.

Comment: It is showing no instance(s) available

Comment: Iam new to batch script i didn't understand any code mentioned above can you please edit the code according to my requirement

Comment: It would make no sense for us to change the one line of code that needs to be changed or added if you do not understand what the rest of the code is doing.  That is just giving a man a fish instead of teaching them to fish.  If you need to have the script work on a specific directory then add a change directory command to the top of the script.

Comment: Thanks It worked(change directory command)

Answer (score 2):

Save yourself all of that code and use `PowerShell` instead!

```ps1
GCI 'C:\Users\UserName\Folder'|?{!$_PSIsContainer -And $_.LastWriteTime -LT (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-20)}|Rm -Wh
```

Change `C:\Users\UserName\Folder` to your specified folder.

*If you're happy with the output, remove `-Wh` from the end and run it again to perform the actual deletion.*

You can do the same thing from a batch file if you want to:

***Warning this already has the `-Wh` removed***

```bat
@PowerShell -C "GCI 'C:\Users\UserName\Folder'|?{!$_PSIsContainer -And $_.LastWriteTime -LT (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-20)}|Rm"
```